# Foundation 5 Website Showing 768px width On IPAD4

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

My foundation 5 website is showing up as 768px on an ipad 4 and I don't know why.
I have set this meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0"  />
```

It's causing a lot of the content to shift around into 'medium' mode. Am I missing something here?

I don't have a way of showing off the code as it's a local development server we're using.

EDIT: My solution was to simply define 'medium' grid values for ipad. So where I had a large-6 I had to also have a medium-6 or it defaulted to width: 100%;

Comment: Try changing `maximum-scale=1.0` into `initial-scale=1`

Comment: Had the same issue with bootstrap last week. @ether comment will fix it, or at least it did in Bootstrap.